# application shutting down in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot project in configuration file there is a task executor whose code goes like this

```
@Bean(name = "asyncExec")
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("CashFlowThread-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

I am deploying an API which download from s3 bucket and create 4 pdf and store it in target folder . while the api is called console shows error that asyncExec is shutting down .

Stack trace for it shows

```
Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-01 17:04:30.174  INFO 3680 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-01 17:04:30.179  INFO 3680 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2020-12-01 17:04:30.185  INFO 3680 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-17 - Starting...
2020-12-01 17:04:35.767  INFO 3680 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-17 - Start completed.
File is created!
Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object
2020-12-01 17:04:43.907  INFO 3680 --- [     Thread-174] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'asyncExec'
2020-12-01 17:04:43.907  INFO 3680 --- [     Thread-174] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-17 - Shutdown initiated...
```

Comment: can you show the error with a complete stack trace

Comment: @Deadpool done.

Comment: @Deadpool the stack trace shows while hitting the rest service

Comment: where are you deploying this code and exactly when this shutdown happens ? Have you added spring-boot-starter-web dependency ?

Comment: @Shawrup check it again now Please.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml or build.gradle file? And also how are you starting your app ? Are you deploying it on an ec2 over ssh or locally with bootrun or some other way?